# Couldn't Crypt::decrypt from artisan command Laravel/Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, lumen, laravel-artisan

I'm working on a project that need to store encrypted information, the store, update, show (used in the Controller) work fine when using `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;`

But when i need to create a Command to run in schedule, in that Command i need to get the unencrypted code, but when i use it, it show

> The MAC is invalid

**Note**: when i use `use Crypt;`, the code in the Controller work fine, but in the Command, it said

> Class 'Crypt' not found

**The code in Command (function `topupSim()` cause the error):**

```
public function handle()
{
    Log::info("** TopUpForCriticalSimsCommand: started");

    $sims = Sim::getCriticalSims();
    foreach ($sims as $sim) {
        $telco_id = $sim->telco_id;

        //Find topup code with same telco
        $topup_code = TopupCode::getAvailableCode($telco_id);

        if ($topup_code) {
            /** @var TopupCode $topup_code */
            if (Engine::topupSim($sim, $topup_code)){
                Log::info("** TopUpForCriticalSimsCommand: topup success
                 for {$sim->phone_number} with code {$topup_code->getCensoredCode()}");
            }else{
                Log::info("** TopUpForCriticalSimsCommand: topup fail
                 for {$sim->phone_number} with code {$topup_code->getCensoredCode()}");
            }
        }
    }

    Log::info("** TopUpForCriticalSimsCommand: finished");
}
```

**`topupSim` function, code that use Crypt:**

```
public static function topupSim(Sim $sim, TopupCode $topupCode)
{
    $code = $topupCode->getCode();
    $serial = $topupCode->getSerial();

    //TODO: Do topup for sim
    if (false /*Success*/) {

        $topupCode->setUse();

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

2 function `getCode()`, `getSerial()` are using Crypt, these 2 functions are in the Model

```
public function getCode()
{
    $code = Crypt::decrypt($this->getAttribute('code'));
    return $code;
}

public function getSerial()
{
    $serial = Crypt::decrypt($this->getAttribute('serial'));
    return $serial;
}
```

Log file:

```
[2016-08-19 02:58:57] lumen.INFO: ** TopUpForCriticalSimsCommand: started  
[2016-08-19 03:01:02] lumen.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException' with message 'The MAC is invalid.' in D:\working-tools\xampp\htdocs\VedSmsGateway\source\sms_gateway\vendor\illuminate\encryption\BaseEncrypter.php:48
Stack trace:
#0 D:\working-tools\xampp\htdocs\VedSmsGateway\source\sms_gateway\vendor\illuminate\encryption\Encrypter.php(96): Illuminate\Encryption\BaseEncrypter->getJsonPayload('eyJpdiI6InBFT2d...')
#1 D:\working-tools\xampp\htdocs\VedSmsGateway\source\sms_gateway\vendor\illuminate\support\Facades\Facade.php(218): Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter->decrypt('eyJpdiI6InBFT2d...')
#2 D:\working-tools\xampp\htdocs\VedSmsGateway\source\sms_gateway\app\Models\TopupCode.php(114): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('decrypt', Array)
#3 D:\working-tools\xampp\htdocs\VedSmsGateway\source\sms_gateway\app\Models\TopupCode.php(114): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::decrypt('eyJpdiI6InBFT2d...')
#4 D:\working-tools\xampp\htdocs\VedSmsGateway\source\sms_gateway\app\Engine.php(721): Ved\SmsGateway\Models\TopupCode->getCode()
#5 D:\working-tools\xampp\htdocs\VedSmsGateway\source\sms_gateway\app\Console\Commands\TopUpForCriticalSimsCommand.php(57): Ved\SmsGateway\Engine::topupSim(Object(Ved\SmsGateway\Models\Sim), Object(Ved\SmsGateway\Models\TopupCode))
#6 [internal function]: Ved\SmsGateway\Console\Commands\TopUpForCriticalSimsCommand->handle()
#7 D:\working-tools\xampp\htdocs\VedSmsGateway\source\sms_gateway\vendor\illuminate\container\Container.php(507): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 D:\working-tools\xampp\htdocs\VedSmsGateway\source\sms_gateway\vendor\illuminate\console\Command.php(169): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#9 D:\working-tools\xampp\htdocs\VedSmsGateway\source\sms_gateway\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(256): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#10 D:\working-tools\xampp\htdocs\VedSmsGateway\source\sms_gateway\vendor\illuminate\console\Command.php(155): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 D:\working-tools\xampp\htdocs\VedSmsGateway\source\sms_gateway\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(791): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 D:\working-tools\xampp\htdocs\VedSmsGateway\source\sms_gateway\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(186): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Ved\SmsGateway\Console\Commands\TopUpForCriticalSimsCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 D:\working-tools\xampp\htdocs\VedSmsGateway\source\sms_gateway\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(117): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 D:\working-tools\xampp\htdocs\VedSmsGateway\source\sms_gateway\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Console\Kernel.php(69): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#15 D:\working-tools\xampp\htdocs\VedSmsGateway\source\sms_gateway\artisan(35): Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 {main}
```

i tried:

```
composer dump-autoload
composer clear-cache
```

but no success

Anyone know, please help, thanks in advance

Comment: this thread may bring info [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070732/laravel-decryptexception-the-mac-is-invalid/47926508#47926508](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070732/laravel-decryptexception-the-mac-is-invalid/47926508#47926508)

Answer (score 1):

OK, so my project consist 2 smaller projects linked together (admin site and api/backend)

The problem was the `key` in config/app.php in the api/backend side is different from the admin site. I've changed `APP_KEY` in .env, now everything is working fine!